# How to manipulate style/atributes in React DOM

Tags: reactjs, dynamic, ref

I have two components. If I hovered over one I'd like to move (by changing style proporties) the other one component.

How can I achieve that?

In pure js it's simply

```
let elem1 = document.querySelector('.elem1');
let elem2 = document.querySelector('.elem2');

elemt1.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
 elem2.style.right = "200px" //or any other style property
})
```

So.. in react we can use "ref" and this works if I define static ref

```
 import React, {Component} from 'react';

class MainCanvas extends Component {

    onHover(){
        console.log(this.refs.mybtntest);

    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <h1 onMouseEnter={() => this.onHover()}> Testing</h1>
                <button ref="mybtntest">Close</button>
            </div>
        );

    }

}
export default MainCanvas
```

However in my case I need to each component should has dynamically added "ref" atribute.. so my code looks like below

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

    class Test extends Component {

        onHover(e, dynamicRef){
            console.log(dynamicRef); //correct number of ref
            console.log(this.refs.dynamicRef); //undefined
            console.log(this.refBtnName); //button reference but eachtime is overrided
            console.log(this.dynamicRef);//undefinded

        }

        render(){

            const elements = this.props.elements.map( element => {
                let refBtnName = element.id + "btn";
                  return [
                    <ComponentElement
                        onHover={(e) => this.onHover(e, refBtnName)}
                        key={element.id} {...element}
                    />,
                    <button key={element.id*2}
                        ref={refBtnName => this.refBtnName = refBtnName}  //each time he will be overrided :(
                        className={`${refBtnName} deleteComponentBtn`} >
                        Close
                    </button>
                 ]

             })
            return(
                <div>
                    {elements}
                </div>
            );

        }

    }
    export default Test
```

A real goal is that I want to positioning the button relative to the element. I could use div for this purpose as a wrapper but I don't want it.
 So I thought to use for example this piece of code

```
onHover(e, dynamicRef){
    Math.trunc(e.target.getBoundingClientRect().right)
    dynamicRef.style.right = `${right}px`;
}
```

Comment: You can use this syntax: `ref={ref => this[refBtnName] = ref}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need dynamic object keys you shouldn't use the dot `.` and instead use the brackets:

```
ref={ref=> this[refBtnName] = ref}
```

Note that i changed the inline parameter to `ref` instead of `refBtnName` so you won't get variable names conflicts.

Running example:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    items: [
      { name: 'John', id: 1 },
      { name: 'Mike', id: 2 },
      { name: 'Jane', id: 3 },
    ]
  }

  move = refName => e => {
    this[refName].style.right = '-90px';
  }

  render() {
    const { items } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {
          items.map(item => {
            return (
              <div key={item.id} >
                <div
                  ref={ref => { this[item.name] = ref }}
                  style={{ position: 'relative' }}
                >
                  {item.name}
                </div>
                <button onClick={this.move(item.name)}>Move {item.name}</button>
              </div>
            )
          })
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
 <div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this works for you. I get 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'left' of undefined' even though my ref correctly retrieves the element.

Comment: @ChristianVermeulen note the signature of the event handler, this is a curried function (a function that returns a function)